# Sample data from a given distribution using Distributions.jl with a vector of different parameters

Tags: types, julia, distribution

I think I can find a few different hacks to do what I want, but I am unsure what is considered best practice in Julia.

I want to write a function to generate samples from a given distribution type with different parameters. Using the Distributions.jl package, it seems like I need to create an object of the appropriate distribution for each set of parameters, passing those parameters as arguments. To do this I need to somehow pass the type of the distribution, then create objects from that type. Is it best to use a parametric function here? Or have a distribution object parameter and use typeof?

My current code is below, and it appears to work, but it feels kludge-y to me to have to pass a random object to specify the distribution type, rather than passing the type itself in a more elegant way.

```
function generateSamples(dist::UnivariateDistribution, thetas::AbstractVector, numSamples::Array{Int64,1}; shuffled=true)
    @assert length(thetas) == length(numSamples)
    M=length(thetas)
    N=sum(numSamples)
    data=zeros(Float64, N)
    n=0
    for i in 1:M
        n_i=numSamples[i]
        dist_i=typeof(dist)(thetas[i]...)
        for j in 1:n_i
            data[n+j]=rand(dist_i)
        end
        n+=n_i
    end
    if shuffled
        shuffle!(data)
    end
    return data
end
```

Comment: Here's a one-liner that you could turn into a function: `vcat([ rand(SomeDistribution(paramvec[k]), numobsvec[k]) for k = 1:length(paramvec) ]...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it,

```
using Distributions

function foo(::Type{T}, numsamples, dist_parameters...) where T<:Distribution
    dist = T(dist_parameters...)
    ...
end

foo(Normal, 5)
```

I do not know what kind of distribution parameters you'll require so you may not use `Varargs` at the end of signature. I think this is a good practice and Julia-way to do it(i.e. to create an array of integer 0s, you'd call `zeros(Int, ...)`)

https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods-1

https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/

Comment: That looks like exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I just wasn't sure whether it should be foo{T}(stuff) or foo(::T, stuff) or foo(::Type{T}) or what.